# EF LINQ: Get self referencing (many to many) ICollection items in async manner

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asynchronous

I try to query all *RelatedArtist* from an *Artist* which I find by *ArtistId* in an `async` manner.

**Class**

```
 public class Artist
 {
      public int ArtistId { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<Artist> RelatedArtists {get;set;}
 }
```

**Context**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Artist>()
          .HasMany(x => x.RelatedArtists)
          .WithMany().Map(x =>
          {
              x.MapLeftKey("ArtistId");
              x.MapRightKey("RelatedArtistId");
              x.ToTable("RelatedArtists");
          });
```

**None async query**

```
 Context.Artists.First(x => x.ArtistId == artistId)
      .RelatedArtists
      .ToList()
```

**SQL Query with the expected result**

```
 SELECT * FROM Artists where ArtistId IN (
      SELECT [RelatedArtistId]
      FROM [dbo].[RelatedArtists]
      WHERE artistId = 740
 )
```

How can I make an async EF Linq query which will execute the query (or very similar) described above.

Comment: You can use `QueryableExtensions` which provides many `async` methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using EF 6 you can use `FirstOrDefaultAsync` extension method :

```
var entity=await Context.Artists.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ArtistId == artistId);
if(entity!=null)
{
 var list=entity.RelatedArtists.ToList();
}
```

If you want to see the list of all async methods you can use, go to this [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions(v=vs.113).aspx) to see all `IQueryable<T>` extension methods.

Code First will take uni-directional associations as one to many, now if you decide to map the FK in your model to identify the root `Artist`, your query could be much better:

```
public class Artist
{
  public int ArtistId { get; set; }

  public int? RelatedToId{ get; set; }
  public virtual Artist RelatedTo {get;set;}

 public virtual ICollection<Artist> RelatedArtists {get;set;}
}
```

The configuration of this relationship using Fluent Api would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Artist>().HasOptional(a=>a.RelatedTo).WithMany(a=>a.RelatedArtist).HasForeignKey(a=>a.RelatedToId);
```

Then your query would be as follow:

```
var list =await Context.Artists.Where(a=>a.RelatedToId==artistId).ToListAsync();
```

### Update:

You could try this:

```
var list= await Context.Artists.Where(a=>a.RelatedArtists.Any(e=>e.Id==artistId)).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: And `.ToListAsync()` to load `RelatedArtists`

Comment: That was the first that I thought, but the type of that navigation property is `ICollection<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`, that's way I decide to go for `FirtsOrDefaultAsync` ;)

Comment: Can it not be done in a single 'query'? Similar to the none async solution?

Comment: I don't think this will work as an Artist can be related to many other artists instead of one. A single 'RelatedToId' implies it is only related to 1 artist.

Comment: @Frank,you already have a one to many relationship, but you are not mapping one of the ends of your relationship. If you check your DB you will see you already have a FK column called `Artist_ArtistId` that EF is handling for you right now. What I propose is map that FK to identify your root artist without the necessity to load it first.

Comment: @octavioccl I don't have the Artist_ArtistId as made change in my Context - See updated post

Comment: Yes, I noticed now what you really have is a many to many relationship. That changes the things. My second solution is not valid in this case, let me think in another solution.

Comment: The update solution does the lookup the wrong way around. :( I checks if the RelatedArtistId is the Artistid. I put the sql query as I look for in my updated question.